# While browsing, why does my pc suddenly connect to sites using upper port numbers and unknown services?

Tags: 11.10, firestarter

Hello I'm a newbie; a while ago I was browsing thenation.com and then I noticed on the Firestarter status tab that I was connected to three hosts 91.189.92.191/176/181 on ports 44441 and 51501 (unknown services). Previously I only see  http or https on 80, 88, and 443 when browsing. Is this something that i should worry about?

I use Firefox with Anonymox on Oneiric.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is normal. Port 80 and 443 are the ports on the server you are connecting to. For HTTP to work, and to receive the response back, a random high numbered port is opened by the browser for the server to connect to and send data back through.